# in app purchase SKproduct array

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skproduct

Not sure if you'll need more code than this (let me know if you do). I've got most of the code ready for my in app purchases, however, I've come across a problem with these two bits of code:

```
  var productsArray: Array<SKProduct!> = []

 let payment = SKPayment(product: self.productsArray as SKProduct)
```

The error says: 'Array' is not convertible to 'SKProduct'
what am I doing wrong here?? This is the only error that I have. Let me know if you need more code as i'm not sure what is relevant. 
Note: I'm using SpriteKit if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean you're using SpriteKit in lieu of StoreKit. If that's the case, that's your first mistake: you require the StoreKit framework in order to be able to use the SKProduct class.

The issue with your code above is in the second line. You're passing an array of SKProducts instead of a single instance. You can grab the first one by changing "self.productsArray" to "self.productsArray[0]" though I would advise using a known-good index or verifying that the product being grabbed from the array is in fact the product you're trying to pass to SKPayment.

Hope that helps.